# SQL: How to prevent double summing

Tags: postgresql, join, sum

I'm  not exactly sure what the term is for this but, when you have a many-to-many relationship when joining 2 tables and you want to sum up one of the variables, I believe that you can sum the same values over and over again.

What I want to accomplish is to prevent this from happening. How do I make sure that my sum function is returning the correct number?

I'm using PostgreSQL
Example:

```
Table 1                 Table 2
SampleID DummyName      SampleID  DummyItem
1        John           1         5
1        John           1         4
2        Doe            1         5
3        Jake           2         3
3        Jake           2         3
                        3         2
```

If I join these two tables ON SampleID, and I want to sum the DummyItem for each DummyName, how can I do this without double summing?

Comment: What is the result you expect?

Comment: John bought 14 items. But it will double count b/c there are two entries of John in the first table. So I believe it will actually return 28 items. But I want it to return 14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to first aggregate and then do the join:

```
select t1.sampleid, t1.dummyname, t.total_items
from table_1 t1
  join (
    select t2.sampleid, sum(dummyitem) as total_items
    from table_2 t2
    group by t2
  ) t ON t.sampleid = t1.sampleid;
```

---

The real question is however: why are the duplicates in `table_1`?

Comment: @RudyF `table_1` is not a dimension table and has a unique id based on a different metric. But there are information in both tables that I need and the unique id isn't the common denominator in the two tables. I will try this and report back to you!

Comment: Do you think it's possible to speed this up some how? It's fine when I'm doing it for a small sample, but when I apply to a bigger sample, it's taking as long as 15 minutes.

Comment: @icecream12345: please read this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info and then post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a step back and try to assess the database design. Specifically, what rules allow such duplicate data?

To address your specific issue given your data, here's one option: create a temp table that contains unique rows from Table 1, then join the temp table with Table 2 to get the sums I think you are expecting.

Comment: "Table 1 already has a unique id based on a different metric". Doesn't really matter ... if there is a 1:1 relationship between SampleID and Dummyname, that relation should reside in a table of its own (say, SampleMaster, along with other attributes specific to SampleID). You would then be joining SampleMaster with Table 2.

Comment: But will it work if unique rows in Table 1 aren't included in Table 2? I can't join temp table with Table 2 on the unique rows b/c that definition is not in Table 2, right?

Comment: Not sure I understand. If there was a sampleid (the joining column) in table 2 that did not exist in table 1, it wouldn't show up in a join either way.

create temp table temp3 as 
select distinct sampleid, dummyname 
from t1;

Then: 
select dummyname, sum(dummyitem)
from temp3, t2
where temp3.sampleid = t2.sampleid
group by dummyname;